# What is correct when "increase or decrease" is a passive?

Tags: verbs

What is diff between "**as n increases**" with "**when n is increased**"?
Also i know this sentence: "**as n increases, the energy consumption increases**" is correct, when i think n and the energy consumption are **passive** here!! Why do not use we **a past participle form** of them?
Thank.

Comment: A good way to understand this from an English learner is the passive voice is just a "grammatical construction". It's used when the subject of the sentence is the recipient of the action (technically this is called the *[patient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_(grammar)*). This is more about syntax than semantic. Semantically, you might know that something causes the increasing, but if you don't have to always explicitly state the cause (technically, this is called *agent*), and thus you don't always need the passive voice.

Comment: Here is a good example: *The large car stopped outside our house.* Obviously, the car can't stop itself. But because we don't care about the driver in this sentence, the passive voice is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult question, and there is a lot going on. Some is style, and some is grammar.

1. In typical English speech and writing, as you know, the passive voice is often used to de-emphasize or drop the (semantic) subject of the sentence and emphasize the (semantic) object.
2. In scientific writing, the passive voice is normally used when referring to anything that the scientist or his/her coworkers do: e.g. "3 grams of salt were added to the beaker." or "The temperature was increased from 0 degrees Celsius to 10 degrees Celsius."
3. The word "increase" can mean "to go up" or "to cause to go up." This is, I believe, the **root** of your problem. I can say "the temperature increased" or "I increased the temperature" to mean the same thing. Once you accept this, I think you should be happy with the sentence you wrote down.
4. By a combination of (2) and (3), something paradoxical can happen when we talk scientifically; namely, "the temperature was increased" actually EMPHASIZES the subject (it suggests that the temperature is the DEPENDENT variable in the experiment and a scientist PURPOSEFULLY increased it) whereas "the temperature increased" strongly suggests that temperature is the independent variable and the scientist is just observing it.
5. You are looking at social science, so it's like the energy consumption of a society. In this case, n, whatever it is, increased, for whatever reason (this is an observation), and the energy consumption of the society did too. Since the scientist is not controlling, presumably, either variable, the wording as is is appropriate.

Comment: +0.5 I'm a little confused by your use of 'temperature' - does it represent 'n'? ... And OP also asked about 'as' vs 'when': *as* implies the increases are proportional.

Comment: I agree: to me a complete answer will address that "as *x* increases, *y* increases" suggests a scientific context and a directly proportional linkage (such as might be expressed in an equation like Ax + B = y).

Comment: I disagree that "as" implies proportionality. In fact I see nothing wrong with "as the temperature increases, the population increases exponentiality"